# Подгрузка изображений с помощью ajax в плагин wp

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, плагин

Пишу плагин для wp. В данный момент на стадии вывода картинок через плагин с помощью ajax.
Собственно, вот фрагмент кода функции-обработчика на php:

```
if(!empty($_POST['img_filter'])) {
        $source = __DIR__.'/MIW 600/'.$_POST['img_filter'].'.jpg';
        echo $source;
    }
```

и фрагмент кода jQuery:

```
jQuery("#filter_number").on("keyup", function () {
        var d = jQuery("#filter_number").val();
        if(d != null && d != '') {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
                data: {
                    'action': 'ajax_object',
                    'img_filter': d
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    jQuery("#drawing").attr('src', data);
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

После отправки ajax-запроса в "data" содержится путь к файлу, но сама картинка не отображается, а в консоль выводит ошибку:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/OpenServer/domains/wordpress-test/wp-content/plugins/oil-filters/MIW%20600/H1013.jpg`
```

Кто знает, как устранить подобную проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полагаю, что дело в путях. `__DIR__` стоит использовать, когда нужен абсолютный путь к каталогу, а вам вроде нужен url изображения? Попробуйте так

```
$source = WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/oil-filters/MIW%20600/' . $_POST['img_filter'] . '.jpg';
```

Comment: И вправду помогло, спасибо огромное)